# Lifetime may not live long enough when passing account into anchor function

Tags: anchor, rust, accountinfo

I am getting this error when I try to pass an account info into a function and then want to use it in a spl transfer:

[image]

```
  pub fn move_in_direction(
    &mut self,
    direction: u8,
    player: AccountInfo,
    chest_vault: AccountInfo,
    vault_token_account: AccountInfo,
    player_token_account: AccountInfo,
    token_account_owner_pda: AccountInfo,
    token_program: AccountInfo,
    tokenOwnerBump: u8,
) -> Result<()> {
    let mut player_position: Option<(usize, usize)> = None;

    let bump = tokenOwnerBump;
    let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
        from: vault_token_account,
        to: player_token_account,
        authority: token_account_owner_pda,
    };
```

I do not quite understand why I am getting this error. Can someone explain my what it means that a generic argument becomes invariant?
I was using AccountInfo in functions before but only if I afterwards use it in a transfer which has <'info> as generic type i get this error.
So my guess is that <'info> is more specific than AccountInfo without the type but what does 'info actually do?

Answer (score 3):

`'info` is a [lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime.html), a rust concept. tldr is that a struct A that holds a reference to some type B must specify a lifetime. This lets the compiler enforce that A isn't "alive" after B has "died".

Don't worry much, you don't actually have to immediately understand it to write programs on Solana. It's okay to just know what the [definition](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/30d051da843e3da7b27aa1627693b915333471ac/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L19) of AccountInfo is generic over a lifetime, and sometimes you might just have to specify that just like you would for a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, but I still don't understand completely what <'info> actually does. Would be nice if someone could explain this to me.

The solution is to add the generic type <'info> to the function and the parameters.

```
pub fn move_in_direction<'info>(
    &mut self,
    direction: u8,
    player: AccountInfo,
    chest_vault: AccountInfo,
    vault_token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    player_token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    token_account_owner_pda: AccountInfo<'info>,
    token_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    tokenOwnerBump: u8,
) -> Result<()> {
    let mut player_position: Option<(usize, usize)> = None;

    let bump = tokenOwnerBump;
    let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
        from: vault_token_account,
        to: player_token_account,
        authority: token_account_owner_pda,
    };
```